# How to load html content in android

Tags: java, android

I want to load html content on web service call.How Can I load my html content on webview. The result is stored System.out.println(data). I am not able to read this data value in webview.I am creating the constructor as well method but not able to read it.

```
public class Dashboard_Description__page extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton reader_back;
    ArrayList<Reader_Model> actorsList;
    String addCat;
    ActorAdapter adapter;


    WebView webView;
    String alternate_id;
    String bookmarkid;
    String bookmarkfile;
    private String webData;
    String result;

    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard__description__page);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, result, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        // String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
        //webView.loadData(getWebData(), "text/html", null);
        WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML"
                        + "(document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML);");
            }
        };
        // Get Web view
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSONReaderAsyncTask(), "HtmlViewer");
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
        // Load URL
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        Dashboard_Description__page description__page=new Dashboard_Description__page();


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            if(extras == null) {
                alternate_id= null;
                bookmarkid= null;
                bookmarkfile = null;
            } else {
                alternate_id= extras.getString("alternateid");
                bookmarkid= extras.getString("bookmarkid");
                bookmarkfile = extras.getString("bookmarkfile");

            }
        } else {
            alternate_id = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("alternateid");
            bookmarkid= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bookmarkid");
            bookmarkfile= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bookmarkfile");

        }

        // System.out.println(stringCameFromFirstAcvitity);

        //  actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONReaderAsyncTask().execute("https://www.miveive.com/mobile/get_article_detail?", " access_token", "bookmark_file", "alternate_id", "bookmarkId");


        reader_back=(ImageButton)

                findViewById(R.id.reader_back_btn);

        reader_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent dash_back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(dash_back);

            }
        });


    }

    class JSONReaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Dashboard_Description__page.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            String jsonResult = "";
            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", "94529e5dbc6234fc3bbfce7406b8dde9"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookmark_file", bookmarkfile));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alternate_id", alternate_id));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookmarkId", bookmarkid));


                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                int status = 200;

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    //System.out.println("fffff");
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    // JSONObject jsono1 = new JSONObject(data);
                    result = jsono.toString();
                    System.out.println(result);
                    JSONReaderAsyncTask json=new JSONReaderAsyncTask();
                    json.doInBackground();

//                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("images");
//                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
//                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
//                        System.out.println(object.getString("imageLink"));
//
//                        Actors actor = new Actors();
//                       // actor.getReaderImage(object.getString("content"));
//                        actor.getReaderImage(object.getString("imageLink"));
//
//                        System.out.println(object.getString("imageId"));
//
//                //        actor.setDescription(object.getString("imageLink"));
////                        actor.setUrl(object.getString("bookmark_website"));
////
////                        actor.setBookmark_id(object.getString("bookmark_id"));
////                        actor.setAlternate_id(object.getString("alternate_id"));
////                        actor.setBookmark_file(object.getString("bookmark_file"));
////                        actor.setImage(object.getString("bookmark_preview_image"));
//
//                       // actorsList.add(actor);
//                    }
                }
                return true;


                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use the `WebView#loadData()` method.

Comment: i suggest you use webview to load html file into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can load `html` in `webview` as below

```
webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

checkout example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: I am hitting the api and I want to show the api result in webview